# Laravel Sanctum and Nuxt Js returns Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I recently just deployed my Nuxt Js application and i am having trouble with authentication.

I have set the stateful and session domain in my .env as seen below

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=api.example.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=example.com
```

i also have this in my cors.php

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie',],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

In my nuxt.config.js i have the following

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      cookie: {
        endpoints: {
          csrf: {
            url: '/sanctum/csrf-cookie'
          },
          login: {
            url: '/api/login',
          },
          register: {
            url: '/api/register',
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/api/logout',
          },
          user: {
            url: '/api/user',
          }
        },
        user: {
          property: 'data'
        },
      }
    },

    redirect: {
      login: '/auth/login',
      logout: '/auth/login',
      home: '/dashboard',
    },

    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/axios'
    ]
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308
    baseURL: 'http://api.example.com',
    credentials: true
  },
```

I do not know what i am doing wrong could someone please help

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file, Change your SESSION_DOMAIN from **api.example.com** to **.example.com**

And change your axios baseUrl from **http://localhost** to your api endpoint

Comment: I keep getting this error even though the credentials are correct ```{"message":"These credentials do not match our records.","errors":{"email":["These credentials do not match our records."]}}```

Comment: It means the error is coming from your backend. Check if the email is found in the database

Comment: I have been able to solve it.. the problem was that i was trying to hash password twice.